# Enable select control on server side

Tags: asp.net, select

I use two select controls - one for banks that is being asserted in page load,
and the second one is for branches - this one is being loaded in run time (by json)
according to the bank that is selected.

The problem is that I want to enable these selects from server side,

```
selectBanks.Enabled = true;
```

works fine, but

```
selectBranch.Enabled = true;
```

Doesn't work at all. Any help?

Comment: I've done some tidying up (unfortunate typo in there). Seeing the json  you're using to populate the second select would help

Comment: Is the branch `<select>` created at run time or does it exist when the page loads? When does the `selectBranch.Enabled` code run? I think more context is needed; can you post the entire routine surrounding the code you have included?

Comment: hello, the json: $ajax({ url= url. type = "POST". data:dataToSend. ... datatype:"json" ... ect.                                                                 the branch select exists in page load but it contains no values- the values are being loaded at run time...                                                              Unfortunatelly I can't post more code because I cant use copy/paste to the internet (special connection to the internet where I work). But I'll be happy to answer more questions if needed.thank you very much for the help.